# Voximal with Google Streaming as STT

Tags: streaming, voximal

I installed latest voximal stack.
Calls are working.
I setup recognition to use Google Cloud Streaming for STT pasting the JSON credentials into browser, the credentials file created at /usr/share/voximal.
But when I try to test parrot.vxml with a call it fail to create the google_streaming resource and drop the call.
Any clues?

Comment: Can you share some code or an error log? That may help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the logs (interpreter debug) and check the /var/log/voximal/debig.log...
You probably see in the root cause there.